# Will rewording a commit after branch-merge affect the original branch?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-branch

Let's say I have a branch called `dev/feature` that has a few commits and is pushed to a remote. Now I merge `dev/feature` into `master` on my machine, but then I realize I want to reword one of the commits from `dev/feature`.

Is it safe to do that as long as I haven't pushed the new (merged) commits on `master` to the remote? Or could I screw things up for someone else who has already pulled `dev/feature` by rewording the commit on `master`?

I guess what I'm asking is if the commits that were merged into `master` are still "connected" to `dev/feature` somehow?

Comment: How **exactly** do you intend to change the commit message?

Comment: If it's local merge and no one has used the feature branch, no problem. Reset local `master` before the merge,  checkout the feature branch, amend the revision, push to remote (with -f) and it's just magic.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Using the "Reword..." context menu option in IntelliJ. Since the actual commit is the second newest, I think IntelliJ uses rebase internally to perform the rewording.

Comment: @eftshift0 The feature branch is pushed already. The merge into master is done locally, but not pushed.

Comment: that's right. If no one is using the feature branch, you can amend locally and force-push, no problem. And the branch you will reset is _local_ `master` so that you can then retry merging the feature branch

Answer (score 1):

As [zrrbite answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63817883/1256452), you can often tell by whether you must use `git push --force`.  But when is this going to be required?  For those new to Git, much of this is a total mystery.  The way to understand what's going on, and who might be affected by something like this, is to realize a few key points about how Git works internally.

We need to know these things:

- Git is really all about *commits*.  Branch names just help us—and Git—*find* commits.
- Each commit is numbered.  The number on a commit is a big ugly hash ID, rather than just a simple counting number; but it's *unique to that one particular commit*, and *every Git everywhere* will agree that *that* commit gets *that* number.  The way this works is that the hash ID is a cryptographic checksum of the contents of that commit—including both its data (snapshot) and metadata (author and committer name and email, date and time stamps, log message, and so on).
- Git *finds* a commit by its number—its hash ID.  When you connect two Gits to each other, they determine if one has a new commit for the other by inspecting only its hash ID.
- Because of this, *no commit can ever be changed*.  If you extract some existing commit, and fix something about it—such as adding a task ID, or rewording a commit message, or fixing a typo in your name or email address—and then write the new commit back into your own Git repository, what you get is a *new and different commit* with a *new unique hash ID*.

**But if commits can't be changed, how do `git commit --amend` and `git rebase` work?**  The trick here is that we don't normally *find* commits by their commit numbers.  We normally *find* commits—well, one *particular* commit—by a name, such as a branch name.

#### Branch names and commits both point to commits

Each commit's metadata stores the hash ID of a *previous* commit.  Merge commits store the hash ID of the previous commit as usual, but then also at least one *more* previous-commit hash ID.  Let's not worry about the merge commits just yet, and just draw a diagram of a simple linear chain of commits:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

Here, `H` stands in for the hash ID of the *last* commit.  Somewhere inside `H`'s metadata, Git has stored the hash ID of earlier commit `G`.  Git can look up `H` by its hash ID, and thereby find the hash ID of `G`.  Then Git can look up `G` by this hash ID, and thereby find the hash ID of earlier commit `F`.  Git can now look up `F`, and so on.

This means that Git works *backwards*, from the last commit back to the first.  All we need now is some way to find that last commit's hash ID.  That's where the branch name comes in:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <--master
```

When we hold a hash ID, we say that whatever is that holds that hash ID *points to* that commit.  So the branch name `master` points to commit `H`, `H` points to `G`, `G` points to `F`, and so on.  There's our backwards chain of commits.

#### Adding a commit updates the branch name

Suppose we have:

```
...--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
```

and we have commit `H` checked out by virtue of having the name `master` checked out.  That's what the `(HEAD)` is for: in case we have more than one branch name, we need to know which *name* we are using.

If we now create a *new* commit, it gets some new, random-looking, big and ugly hash ID that we'll just call `I`.  New commit `I` points back to existing commit `H`—Git knows to set this up automatically because we're using commit `H` as we make `I`—and once `git commit` has finished writing out `I` and thus found its new hash ID, Git updates the *name* `master` to point to new commit `I`:

```
...--G--H--I   <-- master (HEAD)
```

and now `I` is the last commit on `master`.

If we use `git commit --amend`, what Git does is simple: instead of making new commit `I` point back to existing commit `H`, `git commit` makes new commit `I` point back to `H`'s *parent*, like this:

```
       H
      /
...--G--I   <-- master (HEAD)
```

Git updates the name `master` as usual.  New commit `I` is the last one on the chain.  But what happens to commit `H`?  **Commit `H` still *exists*, but we can't find it**—at least, not using the usual method of starting with the branch name to find the *last* commit, then working backwards.  Working backwards from `I` leads us to `G`, which leads us back to an earlier commit: we never see `H` any more.

#### Rebase works by copying commits

Suppose we have this:

```
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J   <-- dev/feature (HEAD)
```

We spot a typo somewhere in commit `I`, perhaps in the source, perhaps in the message.  Either way we need to make a new commit that's *like* `I`, but different: it has the typo fixed.

What we do is get Git to *copy* existing commit `I` to some new commit `I'`, so named because it's like `I`, but fixed-up.  New commit `I'` points back to existing commit `H`, like your existing `I` still does:<sup>1</sup>

```
          I'   <-- ???
         /
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J   <-- dev/feature
```

Having copied `I` to `I'`, we now need to have Git copy `J`.  `J` itself *was* good, but `J` points to `I`.  We need a copy that instead points to `I'`.  So we have Git do that too:

```
          I'-J'  <-- ???
         /
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J   <-- dev/feature
```

Now there's just one thing left to do: Git needs to take the *name* `dev/feature` off `J` and make it point to `J'` instead.  We end up with this:

```
          I'-J'  <-- dev/feature (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J   [abandoned]
```

and the rebase is done.

---

<sup>1</sup>I've used the question-marks here to paper over the trick that Git uses, which is what it calls its *detached HEAD mode*, without having to describe it properly. ;-)

---

#### Other repositories

When we make commits, they get new hash IDs, which are unique to the new commits.  Other repositories don't have these commits yet.  But now, *before we do our `git rebase`*, we will send these new commits to some other Git repository, which in our Git, we call `origin`.  We run:

```
git push origin dev/feature
```

Our Git calls up their Git and the two Gits have a conversation.  We offer them commit `J` because our `dev/feature` names commit `J`.  They say: *Oh, hey, I don't have that commit, please send it.*  We are now obligated to offer them `J`'s parent commit `I` and they don't have that one either, so we offer the commit `H`, but this time they do have it.  So the list of commits we need to send consists of just `I` and `J`.

Our Git will now package up `I` and `J` (and associated stuff like any new files) and send them over.  (Our Git knows what's *new* because they said they have `H`, which we also have, so we can tell!)  They save those away temporarily—they might decide not to keep them—and our Git does its last `git push` steps: *Other Git, now I want you to create or update **your** name `dev/feature` to remember commit `J`.  Is that OK?*

If they say *yes, that's fine, it's done*, our Git knows that they took our `git push`.  Our Git will create or update *our* `origin/dev/feature` to remember this.

If they say *no*, they will also supply some reason, such as "not a fast-forward".  Our Git will print an error message and include the reason, and *won't* create or update our `origin/dev/feature`.

#### Merging

We'll skip right over the mechanism by which `git merge` combines different changes, and look only at the final commit that gets made; but we'll also look at what Git calls, misleadingly, a *fast-forward merge*.  I say "misleadingly" because these are not merges at all.

To cause a merge to happen in our Git repository, we run:

```
git checkout somebranch   # choose where we want to be
git merge otherbranch     # choose which commit to merge
```

In some cases, Git *must* make a real merge to do this.  I draw my standard example of such a case like this:

```
       I--J   <-- somebranch (HEAD)
      /
...--H
      \
       K--L   <-- otherbranch
```

The merging process finds commit `H`, which Git calls the *merge base*, diffs `H`'s snapshot against both `J`'s snapshot and `L`'s snapshot, combines the two diffs, applies the combined diffs to `H`'s snapshot, and makes a new commit.  Again, we're completely ignoring this combining *process*, which is the hard part, and just looking at the new *commit*.  We use the next letter `M` to stand in for this commit's hash ID.

For new commit `M` to be a merge commit, it must have two parents.  That is, it must point back to two existing commits.  One is the same standard commit as always: the commit we have checked out right now, i.e., commit `J`, through the name `somebranch`, to which `HEAD` is attached.  The other parent is the commit we named on the command line: commit `L`, to which the name `otherbranch` points.  Git then updates the current branch name as usual, so the result is:

```
       I--J
      /    \
...--H      M   <-- somebranch (HEAD)
      \    /
       K--L   <-- otherbranch
```

Now, working back from the name `somebranch`, we find commit `M`, then we find *both* commits `J` and `L`, and *both* commits `I` and `K`, and then commit `H` and so on.  Working back from the name `otherbranch`, we find `L`, then `K`, then `H`, and so on.  So the new *merge commit* is only on `somebranch`, but commits `K` and `L` are now on *both branches*, through this new merge commit.

We get a *fast-forward* instead of a merge if and only if two conditions hold:

1. We must have a situation that doesn't have a fork in it, such as:

   ```
   ...--H   <-- somebranch (HEAD)
         \
          I--J   <-- otherbranch
   ```

   This makes it possible for Git to "cheat", as it were.
2. We must *not* tell Git not to cheat, i.e., we must *not* use the `--no-ff` command line flag.  (We are allowed to tell Git: *do this only if you **can** cheat*, using the `--ff-only` flag.)

If Git can and does do a fast-forward, we get:

```
...--H--I--J   <-- somebranch (HEAD), otherbranch
```

That is, Git just checks out their commit while also dragging our current branch name "forwards".  Now, working back from either name, we find the same set of commits.  There is no new merge commit.

#### If you now rebase and reword, Git must copy some commits

Regardless of how you ran `git merge` and whether any *other* Git has any of these commits, none of the existing commits can be changed.  So you might have:

```
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J   <-- dev/feature (HEAD)
```

If you already sent those two commits to `origin`, and it took them, you'll actually have this:

```
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J   <-- dev/feature (HEAD), origin/dev/feature
```

Note that your Git still has the same set of commits.  You just have one extra *name*—a *remote-tracking name* rather than a branch name—that finds commit `J`.  This name, which is only in *your* Git repository, remembers for you that some other Git, over at `origin`, has *its* `dev/feature` name pointing to its copy of commit `J`.

If you now copy `I` and `J` to a fixed-up `I'` and new `J'`, you get:

```
          I'-J'  <-- dev/feature (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J   <-- origin/dev/feature
```

Your remote-tracking name remembers that *their* Git's `dev/feature` still selects original commit `J`.

#### What if you've already done a merge?

If you have already done a `git checkout master; git merge --no-ff dev/feature` to make a real merge, you'll start with:

```
...--G--H------M   <-- master (HEAD)
         \    /
          I--J   <-- dev/feature, origin/dev/feature
```

If you now `git checkout dev/feature` and use `git rebase -i` to copy `I` to `I'` and then `J` to `J'`, you get:

```
          I'-J'  <-- dev/feature (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H------M   <-- master (HEAD)
         \    /
          I--J   <-- dev/feature, origin/dev/feature
```

Note that existing merge commit `M` is not affected at all!

If you allowed Git to execute a fast-forward instead of making a real merge, you will start with:

```
...--G--H
         \
          I--J   <-- master (HEAD), dev/feature, origin/dev/feature
```

and copying `I` and `J` to new commits—assuming you do it with `git checkout dev/feature` first—produces:

```
          I'-J'  <-- dev/feature (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          I--J   <-- master, origin/dev/feature
```

Note how this now looks like the situation in which Git would do a real merge.  The commit hash IDs of commits `I'` and `J'` differ from those of `I` and `J`, and that's what Git really cares about, so if you now `git checkout master`—which will select old commit `J`—and run `git merge dev/feature`, you will end up with:

```
          I'-J'  <-- dev/feature
         /    \
...--G--H      K   <-- master (HEAD)
         \    /
          I--J   <-- origin/dev/feature
```

#### If you want to be rid of old commits, you must move or discard names for them

Note how, in every case, Git determined what to do by *commits*.  We start with `git checkout somename` to pick a name to attach `HEAD` to.  We're now using that name, and hence the commit to which that name points.  The next operation, whatever it is—merge, rebase, and so on—*finds* commits using that name and/or other names we give it.  Then it operates on those commits.

There are a few Git commands, including `git branch`, that *just* operate on names.  You give them a name (and a commit hash ID if needed), and they try to do something with or to that name, using the hash ID.  The most common `git branch` operation is probably to create a new name pointing to the current commit:

```
...--C   <-- somename (HEAD)
```

Run `git branch newbranch` and you get:

```
...--C   <-- somename (HEAD), newname
```

By leaving out the specific commit, you told `git branch` to use the current commit, so Git looked up the name `HEAD`, found the name `somename`, and looked up the name `somename` and found commit `C`.  You can now safely run `git branch -d newname`, which tells Git to remove the name `newname`:

```
...--C   <-- somename (HEAD)
```

If you have a commit that nobody else has, with a name for it, like this:

```
...--H   <-- master
      \
       I   <-- experiment
```

and you tell your Git to *delete* the name `experiment`, you end up with:

```
...--H   <-- master
      \
       I   [abandoned]
```

with no easy way to *find* the hash ID for commit `I`—so you won't see it any more.

#### `git push --force`

If you have run `git push`, you've first handed some commit(s) over to some other Git, then *asked them to set one of their names*.  So *they* have a name for that commit, and they will be able to find it.  If you have replaced that commit with a new and improved one, you can easily *send* the new commit:

```
       I'  <-- branch (HEAD)
      /
...--H   <-- master
      \
       I   <-- origin/branch
```

but now when you ask *their* Git to set *their* name `branch` to point to the replacement commit `I'`, they will say *no*, because if they do that, *they* won't be able to remember the hash ID of original commit `I`.

Their Git doesn't keep track of where they *got* commit `I`.  They know only that they *do have it now*, and if they obey your request to make their name `branch` identify commit `I'`, they won't be able to use that name to find `I` any more.  So a regular `git push` will get you an error.

You can:

- ask them to *delete* their name `branch`, which they might be willing to do without `--force`, or
- use `git push --force` or `git push --force-with-lease` to turn your Git's polite request into a more forceful command.

That is, instead of having your `git push` end with: *Please, if it's OK, set your name `branch` to point to ______* (your Git fills in the blank with the hash ID for `I'`), you simply have your `git push` end with: *And now set your name `branch` to point to _____!*  They *might* reject this anyway, but the default is for them to accept the command.

The `--force-with-lease` option adds a safety check.  Your own Git has your own `origin/branch`, remembering where you think their `branch` points.  Your `git push` now ends with: *I think your `branch` is set to _____.  If so, change it to _____.  Either way, let me know.*  Your Git fills in the first blank from your remote-tracking name, and the second one from what you want them to do.

#### A few last notes

We saw above that `git rebase -i` didn't copy the merge commit, but the way we *ran* `git rebase -i`, we didn't ask it to copy the merge commit.  It's important to realize that by default, *any* `git rebase` simply *doesn't bother* copying merge commits.  This is at least in part because it's too hard to copy them.

There is a flag to `git rebase`, available since Git 2.18: `git rebase -r` tells rebase to *re-perform* merges, in order to preserve commit graph topology.  Note that this still doesn't actually *copy* a merge: it just runs `git merge` all over again.

There is no easy way to get `git rebase` to adjust multiple different branch names at the same time.  That is, given a chain of commits, or a sub-graph that `git rebase -r` can copy, there could be multiple names (branch and/or tag names) that point to commits within the chain or sub-graph.  The new interactive and `-r` machinery now has an obvious place to add label updating commands, but the commands do not yet exist and there is no clear way to choose how to drive this if such a thing were added (but Git does need such a facility).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an attempt at a small "proof" of the safety of amending commits that are not public (have not been pushed) like you're suggesting. Let's say we have one commit 39e761 and two local repositories with the same remote: "origin".

```
/mnt/d/dev/git/change-history-1 [master]
20:35 $ git ls -1
39e7616 (HEAD -> master) Change to test
```

We can see that the remote origin reference file for both repositories `.git\refs\remotes\origin\master` point to the following object:

```
39e7616f7f5b7658829b795ff8e4f1d70f508be9
```

Now let's merge something, or create a new commit locally in repository 1 and "reword", or amend it (becomes `bd9d987`):

```
/mnt/d/dev/git/change-history-1 [master]
bd9d987 (HEAD -> master) Amend: Change to some new, local commit 
39e7616 Change to test
```

You can see that the hash pointed to by the remote reference to origin contains a hash that is further down the masters history. Since you're not modifying this object, you're safe to push and in the process update the remote reference for everybody (when they fetch). Git will also notify you if you're about to do something naughty and would need to 'force' push because you're effectively "changing history".

If you *were* changing history you would of course be required to:

```
git push --force
```

or more safely:

```
git push --force-with-lease
```